# Which is the best and fast way of access value from NSDictionary using key in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

There are following ways for accessing value from  NSDictionary:

```
studentInfo.objectForKey["name"]
studentInfo["name"]
```

So my question is which is fast and best way out of these, and I would like to know advantages and disadvantages of those it respectively.

Comment: why people give minus to this question ?

Comment: Probably because it is something it can be found with a simple Google search

Comment: no i can't found which is better and faster thats why I posted this question

Comment: Have you tried using `CACurrentMediaTime()` to measure how fast they execute?

Comment: No, I don't know that thing. Thanks for inform will try it now.

Comment: @PravinTate Why do you care?

Answer (score 2):

Both case is equivalent by "speed". IMHO second one is shorter and better. `objectForKey` is just inherited from Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

For `NSDictionary` there is no difference what to use. Use same way you prefer to use in **Objective-C**.

But better option is to start using **Swift**'s native `Dictionary` collection

Comment: I need to know which is faster out of these if I am using NSDictionary ?

Comment: subscript method probably just wraps `objectForKey` so there should be no difference in speed